# Change font of cell in DataGrid on Windows Mobile

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, datagrid, compact-framework

I'm using VS 2005 to create a Windows Mobile program in C#.  I need to display data in a grid.  The only grid control I could find for Windows Mobile is DataGrid, so I placed one on my form.  I now need to change the width of some columns and the font & color of some cells.  How do I do this?

Also is there is a better control to use for Windows Mobile?

thanks
John.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out I am running into the same problem.  Everyone uses the example of binding to a DataTable but I am using custom objects or DataReaders and their examples don't work.

Comment: sorry, but I was never able to figure out how to change the font of only some cells.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you can change the font for individual columns or cells. The grid has a property that lets you set the font and size.
To set the width of columns, I use this method (it adds a table style to the grid):

```
private void SetColumnWidth(int columnID, int width)
{
    // add table style if first call
    if (this.dataGrid1.TableStyles.Count == 0)
    {
        // Set the DataGridTableStyle.MappingName property
        // to the table in the data source to map to.
        dataGridColumnTableStyle.MappingName = "<name of your table in the DS here>";

        // Add it to the datagrid's TableStyles collection
        this.dataGrid1.TableStyles.Add(dataGridColumnTableStyle);
    }

    // set width
    this.dataGrid1.TableStyles[0].GridColumnStyles[columnID].Width = width;
}
```

This method is also helpful when you want to hide a column that is in the bound DataTable, but you don't want to show (then you set width = 0).

Comment: I added the function you posted however I got the error 

The name 'dataGridColumnTableStyle' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. You need to create a DatagridTableStyle instance for your form. You can do that at design time or in the code. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984371(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have to do custom painting.  The CF team [blogged about how to do it here](http://blogs.msdn.com/netcfteam/archive/2006/04/25/583542.aspx).